# Create New record in multiple tables Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert, ms-access-2013

I want to create a new record in multiple tables.
First I want to make a record in `personen` then I want to use the `personen_ID` to make foreign keys in each of the other tables.
These tables are linked by a primary key in the `personen` table and a foreign key in each `gegevens` table.

I have these tables:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAAdO.jpg]

Is this even possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just to clarify: You want to add a person in `Personne` and automatically have the other tables updated? Do you need some other or all other tables updated?

Comment: And what have you looked at so far? Have you tried anything, or read up on this?

Comment: Please describe the method you're using to add the new record to your *Personen* table.  Also, what is the datatype of *Personen.personen_ID*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an After Insert [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) on the [Personen] table to create the rows in the other tables:

[image: AfterInsert.png]